# Имитационное моделирование

Tags: терминология, моделирование, имитационное-моделирование

Разбирался с классификацией имитационного моделирования. Нашел среди всего [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7i6REI9tNCY&ab_channel=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) :
Помогите пожалуйста понять, верно ли я понимаю, что агентное от дискретно-событийного отличается тем, что агентное направлено на детально рассмотрение КАЖДОЙ сущности, а дс на системы в целом и её поведения в зависимости от генерации транзактов и параметров элементов системы.

И ГЛАВНЫЙ ВОПРОС : откуда берётся система оду на 4:51? Почему она именно соду, а не слау???

Comment: Это точно по программированию? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Целью имитационного моделирования вне зависимости от метода моделирования, как правило, является исследование системы.

При *агентном моделировании (АМ)* определяют поведение системы в зависимости от заданного поведения агентов. Вдруг получим эмерджентное (непредвиденное) поведение системы? Реализуется схема моделирования "снизу вверх" - от малого к большему, от частного к общему. Уровень абстракции - низкий. Это значит, что мы способны различить "винтики" системы, которые приводят её в движение.

**Пример задачи.**
Моделирование транспортных потоков. Каждый агент (водитель) преследует цель добраться из точки A в точку B. Идти ли на обгон, превышать ли скорость и т.д. агент решает, исходя из информации, которая ему доступна. В результате моделирования определяют эффективность транспортной системы (сети дорог, развязок, общественного транспорта и т.д.).

*Дискретно-событийное моделирование (ДСМ)* - это просто подход к моделированию динамических процессов. Время дискретно. Ключевые понятия - **событие** и **процесс**. Между событиями система нас "не интересует". Уровень абстракции - низкий/средний.

АМ и ДСМ вполне можно смешивать. АМ может помочь для ДСМ стохастических систем, когда отсутствует строгая связь процессов, вследствие чего агент должен предпринимать действия (инициировать процессы и события) в зависимости доступной ему информации.

**Пример задачи.**
Моделирование работы промышленного предприятия (закупки, производство, сбыт и т.д.). Как правило, при таком моделировании пытаются найти узкие места с целью их устранения и повышения эффективности системы (производства).

В *системной динамике (СД)* оперируют представлением системы на довольно высоком уровне абстракций, т.е. не выделяются отдельные акторы (например, люди, отдельные механизмы и т.д.). Методы системной динамики используются в таких программах, как [Simulink](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink.html) и [SimInTech](https://simintech.ru/).

**Примеры задач.**
В основном СД используется для моделирования технических систем, процессов управления ими. Но может использоваться и для моделирования социальных систем.

Что касается **главного вопроса**.
Динамика означает изменение чего-либо во времени. В данном случае, со временем изменяется состояние системы, а ещё конкретнее уровни `L1`, `L2` и т.д. Так случилось (спасибо Ньютону и другим гигантам), что динамические процессы описываются диффурами, а не СЛАУ. В видео на 4:52 формулами записаны простые соображения:

1. Изменение числа здоровых `L1` за бесконечно малое время есть разность потоков (интенсивностей) выздоравливающих больных `F1(L2)` (поток зависит от числа больных в текущий момент времени) и заболевающих здоровых `F2(L1, L2)`. Поток `F1` увеличивает `L1`, `F2` - уменьшает (знак "-"). Конкретный вид функций потоков выбирается с опорой на опытные данные, статистику, теорию и т.д.
2. Аналогично и с `L2`: в этом случае поток `F2` увеличивает `L2`, `F1` и `F3` - уменьшают.
3. Уровень умерших `L3` со временем может только возрастать за счёт потока `F3`.

Потоки `F1`, `F2` и т.д. могут быть как линейными и иметь очень простой вид (как, например, в [модели Лотки - Вольтерры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D1%8B)), так и нелинейными. Но в результате, как правило, получается нелинейное решение. С помощью СЛАУ невозможно описать потоки (динамику) и итоговые зависимости (разве что в редких частных случаях).